# How to hide the JWindow when I press Enter key?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, intellij-idea

I have a frame and a JWindow. In my frame I have a textfield, whenever I type something to the field, the window will appear with list of suggestions below the textfield. I used a keylistener to the field.
When I press the enter key on the list of suggestion in the window, the word that I select goes to  the field.

Now the problem is that the window still appear, I want the window to disappear whenever I select  a word.

Could someone got an idea about this?

Thanks..

Comment: Do you mean something like `window.dispose();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jWindowInstance.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
      if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
         jWindowInstance.dispose(); // Release resources

         // OR
         jWindowInstance.setVisble(false); // Just hide the window so you can reuse it afterwards
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jWindowInstance.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have an OK button on there, in which case you should be able to set the default button on the root pane of the window, e.g.

```
window.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okBtn);
```

Comment: @Mikel I would do this so (and in case that you don't have a ok button, i would make one)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the selected item to the textbox, right? I assume that you have used some kind of event listener to do that. At the end of the action method, make the window's visibility to false. Swaranga's way should work.

Comment: If you add the code of how you have shown the selected item in the text field, may be I will be able to help you more.